# Using FlowType.js with Flexbox Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexbox

UPDATE: I originally thought this was something between MatchHeight and FlowType but it now appears to be an issue with using flexbox css. I commented out the flex css and FlowType works, but I need it to work with flexbox. Any ideas?

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I have a page where I have 5 blocks with text and images in them. They are organized in a row and I am using matchheight.js to keep them all the same height and FlowType.js so the text will resize within the boxes and keep the proper layout.

Ideally the header text should all be the same size across the boxes as well as the body text.

However when the page first loads some of the boxes have different size text than the others - even though they all have the same base font size and the boxes are the same size.

When I adjust the size of the window everything recalculates and the font sizes become uniform. What is missing when the page loads that causes the text to not size correctly and/or is there a way to trigger the recalculation without resizing the window.

Here is the code I use to call the js.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.front-page-guide').flowtype({
     maxFont: 40,
   });
  $('.front-page-guide').matchHeight();
});
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/dll416/pen/xgeeoz

So you can see the html and css and see it in action.

The viewport has to be 1200px or below to see the issue.

Thx.

Comment: Try calling the matchHeight before the flowtype

Comment: I wish it was that simple. It happens no matter which is called first.